# Protect ASP.MVC controller action using OAUTH

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I need to protect MVC action methods via OAUTH.  Ultimately, I think I need to create two action filters - one to parse the OAUTH data and another to send back data with appropriate headers.  Unfortunately, I can't find any example of this.  Does anyone have pointers or samples they can provide which can get me started?

EDIT - I've already looked at DotNetOpenAuth and the sample they have is for WCF and seems rather complex for this need.  I found https://github.com/bittercoder/DevDefined.OAuth and it does seem promising.  Hopefully, others have found additional userful resources.

Comment: Did you look at [DotNetOpenAuth](http://www.dotnetopenauth.net/)? It contains numerous examples that are worth checking if you intend to do any OAuth with ASP.NET.

Comment: generally what you're talking about is setting up authentication through oauth; where by you say a session is a certain user and fill in some other info for them.

Comment: Yes, I looked at DotNetOpenAuth and the sample they have for protecting a resource is targeted at WCF and is rather complicated for what I need accomplished (protect an MVC REST action).  I am currently looking at https://github.com/bittercoder/DevDefined.OAuth which seems promising.

Comment: >> generally what you're talking about is setting up authentication - actually its authorization not authentication.  A service often does not have a sense of a user since its really an application talking to another application and asking if it can execute a particular method/service.

Comment: You asked if I managed to solve my problem at my post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7348243/2-legged-oauth-implementation-in-c

Is a client side implementation what you need? Or a server side implementation? I managed to solve the client side.